# how to Pass array variable in PHP POST?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, post

would like to ask if its possible/how to pass array variable in php using javascript

i have this following code

```
jQuery("#save").click(function() {


    var val = [];
    jQuery('#themes:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = jQuery(this).val();
    });



    jQuery("#status").load("<?=$config['publicdomain']?>/saveProfile.php?wthemes="+val);


});
```

this is the form field

```
<span>
    <input id="themes" name="themes" type="checkbox" value="theme a">
    <input id="themes" name="themes" type="checkbox" value="theme b">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

First

- [Id must be unique](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html)
- so if you want to use same id then use class instead

Second

- `name="themes"` should be `name="themes[]"`

---

**Good read**

[**jQuery AJAX POST example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example/14217926#14217926)

Answer (score 1):

Your input should be

```
<input type="hidden" id="car" name="vehicle[]" value="car" />
<input type="hidden" id="bike" name="vehicle[]" value="bike" />
<input type="hidden" id="truck" name="vehicle[]" value="truck" />
<input type="hidden" id="cycle" name="vehicle[]" value="cycle" />
<input type="hidden" id="train" name="vehicle[]" value="train" />
```

then in server side

```
<?php

$vehicles=$_POST["vehicle"];

foreach($vehicles as $vehicle){
 // Do your sfuff here
}

?>
```

If using ajax this may help you

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[0]);
   }
```

Comment: "Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks", but
This is a GOOD POST! Thanks. +1